# What do the numbers mean in syslog-ng.d?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, syslog

On Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) the directory `syslog-nd.g` contains syslog configuration files like

```
00-default-destinations
00-default-options
00-default-sources
10-console
```

I am not sure if those files are completely custom made - but if not, what do those numbers imply?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers allow you to control the order the files are processed, so 00 is all the defaults, which can be overridden by files starting with higher numbers.

Comment: Do you have a reference?